# Binwalk - Compressed data is corrupt

Tags: reverse-engineering

```
root@kali:~/ROUTER# binwalk new-firmware.bin 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
84            0x54            uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0xE52A7F50, created: 2012-02-10 07:27:12, image size: 819799 bytes, Data Address: 0x80002000, Entry Point: 0x801AC9F0, data CRC: 0x6A10D412, OS: Linux, CPU: MIPS, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: lzma, image name: "Linux Kernel Image"
148           0x94            LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2386252 bytes
917588        0xE0054         Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 4.0, compression:lzma, size: 2588426 bytes, 375 inodes, blocksize: 16384 bytes, created: 2016-02-05 02:05:56

root@kali:~/ROUTER# dd if=new-firmware.bin of=uboot.lzma skip=148 bs=1
3735488+0 records in
3735488+0 records out
3735488 bytes (3.7 MB, 3.6 MiB) copied, 4.16712 s, 896 kB/s

root@kali:~/ROUTER# dd if=new-firmware.bin of=kernel.squash skip=917588 bs=1
2818048+0 records in
2818048+0 records out
2818048 bytes (2.8 MB, 2.7 MiB) copied, 3.46517 s, 813 kB/s
```

All looks to have worked so far but then I try the following:

```
root@kali:~/ROUTER# lzma -d uboot.lzma 
lzma: uboot.lzma: Compressed data is corrupt

root@kali:~/ROUTER# unsquashfs kernel.squash 
Parallel unsquashfs: Using 4 processors
lzma uncompress failed with error code 0
read_block: failed to read block @0x277af0
read_fragment_table: failed to read fragment table index
FATAL ERROR:failed to read fragment table
```

Any idea why it may be happening? As the prompt says, I am on Kali Linux. ALso get this

```
jj@ubuntu:~/Firmware$ binwalk -e new-firmware.bin 

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
84            0x54            uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0xE52A7F50, created: 2012-02-10 07:27:12, image size: 819799 bytes, Data Address: 0x80002000, Entry Point: 0x801AC9F0, data CRC: 0x6A10D412, OS: Linux, CPU: MIPS, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: lzma, image name: "Linux Kernel Image"
148           0x94            LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 8388608 bytes, uncompressed size: 2386252 bytes

WARNING: Extractor.execute failed to run external extractor 'sasquatch -p 1 -le -d '%%squashfs-root%%' '%e'': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

WARNING: Extractor.execute failed to run external extractor 'sasquatch -p 1 -be -d '%%squashfs-root%%' '%e'': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
917588        0xE0054         Squashfs filesystem, little endian, version 4.0, compression:lzma, size: 2588426 bytes, 375 inodes, blocksize: 16384 bytes, created: 2016-02-05 02:05:56
```

Comment: Perhaps the numbers provided are sizes instead of offsets? In which case you would need to use `skip=84` instead of `skip=148`, so that you are getting to the beginning of the LZMA data...

Comment: Did that and got:     lzma: uboot.lzma: File format not recognized

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
lzma -d < uboot.lzma > uboot
```

The error you found is due to LZMA Utils having been superseded by XV Utils, which don't ignore the trailing garbage. If you use it as a stream (like I gave you), you'll still have the corruption error message in the end, but you'll get your file alright.

[Source](http://www.devttys0.com/2011/05/reverse-engineering-firmware-linksys-wag120n/#comment-46479) (search for "corrupt" and you'll find other related comments)

Comment: I used this method but result file size is so small. Input `lzma` compressed file  is 14815 bytes, output is 22 bytes. I think it is not working.

Answer (score -1):

Try

binwalk -e new-firmware.bin

you will end up with 2 file one being extracted

In the extracted one you will get 2 one unzippped and a zipped one
you can use dd at this point and unlzma should work at least it did work out for me

this is what i mean

root@ROOT20:~/Desktop/project/dlink/dlink2# binwalk dcs932l_v1.14.04.bin

### DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION

106352        0x19F70         U-Boot version string, "U-Boot 1.1.3"
106816        0x1A140         CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
124544        0x1E680         HTML document header
124890        0x1E7DA         HTML document footer
124900        0x1E7E4         HTML document header
125092        0x1E8A4         HTML document footer
125260        0x1E94C         HTML document header
125953        0x1EC01         HTML document footer
327680        0x50000         uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x88345E96, created: 2016-09-09 13:52:27, image size: 3804958 bytes, Data Address: 0x80000000, Entry Point: 0x803B8000, data CRC: 0x531E94DE, OS: Linux, CPU: MIPS, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: lzma, image name: "Linux Kernel Image"
327744        0x50040         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 6558763 bytes

root@ROOT20:~/Desktop/project/dlink/dlink2# dd if=dcs932l_v1.14.04.bin skip=327744 bs=1 of=kernel.lzma
3866560+0 records in
3866560+0 records out
3866560 bytes (3.9 MB, 3.7 MiB) copied, 9.61104 s, 402 kB/s

root@ROOT20:~/Desktop/project/dlink/dlink2# unlzma kernel.lzma
**unlzma: kernel.lzma: Compressed data is corrupt**

root@ROOT20:~/Desktop/project/dlink/dlink2# binwalk -e dcs932l_v1.14.04.bin

### DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION

106352        0x19F70         U-Boot version string, "U-Boot 1.1.3"
106816        0x1A140         CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
124544        0x1E680         HTML document header
124890        0x1E7DA         HTML document footer
124900        0x1E7E4         HTML document header
125092        0x1E8A4         HTML document footer
125260        0x1E94C         HTML document header
125953        0x1EC01         HTML document footer
327680        0x50000         uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x88345E96, created: 2016-09-09 13:52:27, image size: 3804958 bytes, Data Address: 0x80000000, Entry Point: 0x803B8000, data CRC: 0x531E94DE, OS: Linux, CPU: MIPS, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: lzma, image name: "Linux Kernel Image"
327744        0x50040         LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 6558763 bytes

root@ROOT20:~/Desktop/project/dlink/dlink2# ls
dcs932l_v1.14.04.bin  _dcs932l_v1.14.04.bin.extracted  kernel.lzma

root@ROOT20:~/Desktop/project/dlink/dlink2# cd _dcs932l_v1.14.04.bin.extracted/

root@ROOT20:~/Desktop/project/dlink/dlink2/_dcs932l_v1.14.04.bin.extracted# ls
50040  50040.7z

root@ROOT20:~/Desktop/project/dlink/dlink2/_dcs932l_v1.14.04.bin.extracted# binwalk 50040

### DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION

3145804       0x30004C        Linux kernel version 2.6.21
3175792       0x307570        SHA256 hash constants, little endian
3389960       0x33BA08        Unix path: /usr/gnemul/irix/
3392244       0x33C2F4        Unix path: /usr/lib/libc.so.1
3393940       0x33C994        Unix path: /dev/vc/0
3408260       0x340184        Copyright string: "Copyright (c) 2010 Alpha Networks Inc."
3491536       0x3546D0        Unix path: /etc/Wireless/RT2860STA/RT2860STA.dat
3573187       0x3685C3        Neighborly text, "neighbor %.2x%.2x.%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x lost on port %d(%s)(%s)"
3807776       0x3A1A20        CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
4038656       0x3DA000        LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x5D, dictionary size: 1048576 bytes, uncompressed size: 8072704 bytes

root@ROOT20:~/Desktop/project/dlink/dlink2/_dcs932l_v1.14.04.bin.extracted# dd if=50040 skip=4038656 bs=1 of=kernel2.lzma
2520107+0 records in
2520107+0 records out
2520107 bytes (2.5 MB, 2.4 MiB) copied, 8.23342 s, 306 kB/s
root@ROOT20:~/Desktop/project/dlink/dlink2/_dcs932l_v1.14.04.bin.extracted# unlzma kernel2.lzma

root@ROOT20:~/Desktop/project/dlink/dlink2/_dcs932l_v1.14.04.bin.extracted#

root@ROOT20:~/Desktop/project/dlink/dlink2/_dcs932l_v1.14.04.bin.extracted# mkdir cpio; cd cpio

root@ROOT20:~/Desktop/project/dlink/dlink2/_dcs932l_v1.14.04.bin.extracted/cpio# cpio -idm --no-absolute-filenames < ../kernel2
cpio: Removing leading `/' from member names
15767 blocks

root@ROOT20:~/Desktop/project/dlink/dlink2/_dcs932l_v1.14.04.bin.extracted/cpio# ls
bin  dev  etc  etc_ro  home  init  lib  media  mnt  mydlink  proc  sbin  sys  tmp  usr  var